# Login into a website and return login status

Tags: excel, vba, httprequest, httpresponse

I need to login to a list of website and return login status.

I am able to do the validate the URL using below VBA code, but I am not sure how to return the login status.

Script:

```
    Function IsURLValid(URL As String) As Boolean
    

    
    
    Dim Request As Object
    Dim Result  As String

    On Error Resume Next
    

    Set Request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Could not create the WinHttpRequest object!", vbCritical, "WinHttpRequest Error"
        Exit Function
    End If
    
 
    Request.Open "GET", URL, False
    

    Request.send
    
   
    Result = Request.StatusText
            
    
    If InStr(1, Result, "OK", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then IsURLValid = True
    
    
    Set Request = Nothing

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: What isn't working with your code? And did you look at the inbuilt methods for providing status?

Comment: if i am giving  wrong username and password, still it's showing me login status as success only. 

I need to capture success status if it' successfully login else it should through me a different message.